# AUC measure for Local outlier detection in python?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, outliers, auc, localoutlierfactor

I'm using Local outlier factor algorithm provided by Scikit-learn for outlier detection. For the evaluation i want to use auc measure.

```
clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20, contamination=outlier_frac, novelty=False)
pred_y=clf.**fit_predict**(data)

false_postive_rate, true_positive_rate, thresholds = **roc_curve**(labels,  pred_y)

auc_measure=auc(false_postive_rate,true_positive_rate)
```

Unfortunaly roc_curve requires the **predicted probabilities** or **decision function** not the **predicted class labels**. However, LOF for outlier detection  does not contain this.
I tried to create decision function by my self. But i'm not sure about its feasabilty.

```
Scorelist=clf.negative_outlier_factor_
threshold = stats.scoreatpercentile(Scorelist, 100 * outlier_frac)
decision=clf.negative_outlier_factor_-threshold
```

How to obtain the predicted probabilties or the decision function for LOF outlier detection , since there is decision function for LOF novelty detection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way is to apply the logistic or sigmoid function; it works in the majority of the situation, including those when you don't have access to all the scores at once.

```
def normalize_score(scores):
    for index, score in enumerate(scores):
        scores[index] =  1/(1+math.exp(-1*score))
    return scores
```

The above is close to the idea suggested here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling

If you have access to all the scores, then it may be easier to apply one of the scaling methods depending on the distribution of your scores.

(1) min-max scaler https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

(2) standard scaler https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Side note:

LOF from sklearn can be used in two modes, (1) Outlier detector, (2) Novelty detector. Different score functions are available for different modes; for instance decision_function and score_samples can be used in novelty detection mode

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html#sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.decision_function

Answer (score 2):

As you said, Local Outlier Factor works by constructing a distance metric that checks whether a point is distant from its neighbours.

Sklearn returns this metric as `negative_outlier_factor_` where inliers are close to $-1$ while outliers will be bigger than $-1$.

To answer your question, you can either a) take the negative outlier factor and try to assign a probability based on this or b) just make the probabilities either 1 or 0 (so treat the algorithm as being completely certain).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me how can i do the first solution: """take the negative outlier factor and try to assign a probability based on this """

Comment: I would multiply the list of values by minus 1 to make it positive. Then subtract the smallest value from everything so that now the smallest value in the list will be zero. Then divide by the biggest value so now the biggest number is one. Now you have a list of numbers which go from zero to one. I have no idea how well that will work in practice for the purposes of your problem though.